# C++: I'm using a[] , which memory I'm using?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int a[4]; 
}
```

I'm doing static allocation, right? So, where's located a? Stack or Heap?

Comment: Yes, stack allocation.

Comment: I cannot see any new or malloc/calloc/realloc used in this code snippet. What do you think where `a` is located..??

Comment: Well I know that automatic allocation uses Stack, but I did not know that static allocation uses Stack too.

Comment: It seems to me that this is still "automatic allocation", in the sense that "a" only exists when main is called

Comment: So how I can make an example of static allocation?

Answer (score 0):

Any object in C/C++ that is directly declared at function scope is allocated on the stack.
Objects created from the new operator or allocated by functions like C's malloc are allocated on the heap.

Internally, a stack allocated C++ object might have responsibility over heap allocated data, but the object itself would still be on the stack.

In your example, the array is a built-in type with a constant size known at compilation time with no mention of the new operator... Definitely entirely on the stack!

Answer (score 0):

Its stack allocation. Programmer can only create object on heap using functions like malloc,calloc, realloca , or operator like new , new[] . etc. Since you have created array of four integers without specifying any , dynamic memory management routines.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe first we need to clear out the terms. A common variable definition within a scope is called 'automatic'. Your variable definition for instance is automatic. If you want a variable definition to be static then you must use the keyword 'static'.

As for the memory: Automatic variables are located on the stack. Allocated space, e.g. via malloc or new, is located on the heap. Static variables are located on what is called the 'data segment'. For further information look here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/